# predict() function throws error using factors on linear model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

I am using the "lung capacity" data set to try to set up a linear model:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
h <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0BxQfpNgXuWoIWUdZV1ZTc2ZscnM/edit?resourcekey=0-gqXT7Re2eUS2JGt_w1y4vA#gid=1055321634"
t <- rvest::read_html(h)
Nodes <- t %>% html_nodes("table")
table <- html_table(Nodes[[1]])
colnames(table) <- table[1,]
table <- table[-1,]
table <- table %>% select(LungCap, Age, Height, Smoke, Gender, Caesarean)
Lung_Capacity <- table

Lung_Capacity$LungCap <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$LungCap)
Lung_Capacity$Age <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Age)
Lung_Capacity$Height <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Height)
Lung_Capacity$Smoke <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Smoke == "yes")
Lung_Capacity$Gender <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Gender == "male")
Lung_Capacity$Caesarean <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Caesarean == "yes")

colnames(Lung_Capacity)[4] <- "Smoker_YN"
colnames(Lung_Capacity)[5] <- "Male_YN"
colnames(Lung_Capacity)[6] <- "Caesarean_YN"
head(Lung_Capacity)
Capacity <- Lung_Capacity
```

I am splitting the data into a training set and a validation set:

```r
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
y <- Capacity$LungCap
testIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.2, list = FALSE)

train <- Capacity[-testIndex,]
test <- Capacity[testIndex,]
```

Cross-validating to obtain my final model:

```
set.seed(3)
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 5)
LinearModel <- train(LungCap ~ ., data = train, method = "lm", trControl = control)
LM <- LinearModel$finalModel
summary(LM)
```

And trying to run a prediction on the held-out test set:

```
lmPredictions <- predict(LM, newdata = test)
```

However, there is an error thrown that reads:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Smoker_YN1' not found

Looking through this site, I thought the column names of the test and train tables may have been off, but that is not the case, they are identical.  The issue seems to be that training the model has renamed the factor predictors "Smoker_YN1" as opposed to the column name "Smokey_YN" that is intended.  I tried renaming the column headers in the test set and I tried re-naming the coefficient headers.  Neither approach was successful.

I've run out of research and experimental approaches, can anyone please help with this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you have a `1` level in your training data (and the `Smoker_YN1` column is automatically created as a dummy column) but don't have that level in your prediction data?

Comment: After doing a considerable bit of editing to make your code reproducible (i.e. to get to the last step without errors), I can't replicate your error.  Please try starting a **clean R session** and running the code here from start to finish, see if you still get the error.

Comment: PS it's not clear why you're training a linear model by cross-validation; there aren't any settings to tune?

Comment: Yes, but emphasizing that this error is **not reproducible**, at least by me. That may have been what happened, but without reproducible code we will not be able to do more than guess. In the code, the binary variables are all explicitly set to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Please go through and tell me: My guess (and I am not an expert, is that `LungCap` character and `Lung` numeric interfer in this code):

```
h <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0BxQfpNgXuWoIWUdZV1ZTc2ZscnM/edit?resourcekey=0-gqXT7Re2eUS2JGt_w1y4vA#gid=1055321634"
#install.packages("textreadr")
library(textreadr)
library(rvest)
t <- read_html(h)
t
Nodes <- t %>% html_nodes("table")
table <- html_table(Nodes[[1]])
colnames(table) <- table[1,]
table <- table[-1,]
table <- table %>% select(LungCap, Age, Height, Smoke, Gender, Caesarean)
Lung_Capacity <- table


# I changed Lung_Capacity$LungCap <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$LungCap) to
Lung_Capacity$Lung <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$LungCap)

Lung_Capacity$Age <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Age)
Lung_Capacity$Height <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Height)
Lung_Capacity$Smoke <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Smoke == "yes")
Lung_Capacity$Gender <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Gender == "male")
Lung_Capacity$Caesarean <- as.numeric(Lung_Capacity$Caesarean == "yes")

colnames(Lung_Capacity)[4] <- "Smoker_YN"
colnames(Lung_Capacity)[5] <- "Male_YN"
colnames(Lung_Capacity)[6] <- "Caesarean_YN"
head(Lung_Capacity)
# I changed to
Capacity <- Lung_Capacity
Capacity

library(caret)
set.seed(1)
# I changed y <- Capacity$LungCap to 
y <- Capacity$Lung
testIndex <- caret::createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.2, list = FALSE)

train <- Capacity[-testIndex,]
test <- Capacity[testIndex,]

# I removed 
train$LungCap <- NULL
test$LungCap <- NULL

set.seed(3)
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 5)
# I changed LungCap to Lung 
LinearModel <- train(Lung ~ ., data = train, method = "lm", trControl = control)
LM <- LinearModel$finalModel
summary(LM)

lmPredictions <- predict(LM, newdata = test)
lmPredictions
```

Output:

```
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
 6.344355 10.231586  4.902900  7.500179  5.295711  9.434454  8.879997 
        8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
12.227635 11.097691  7.775063  8.085810  6.399364  7.852107  9.480219 
       15        16        17        18        19        20 
 8.982051 10.115840  7.917863 12.089960  7.838881  9.653292
```

Comment: I already edited OP's code so that it would (minimally) run start to finish without errors, and can't reproduce an error. I'm not sure "I can't reproduce this" is a useful answer ...

Comment: Thank you Ben Bolker for your reply. I will leave the answer for a while and remove it after that (1 day).

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I'm really sorry about forgetting the rvest library, my mistake.